# DB2 error in stored procedure when using "scroll" cursor

Tags: stored-procedures, scroll, cursor, db2

I want to use scroll cursor in my DB2 stored procedure, so that I could do absolute position. But after I declare a srcoll cursor like

```
DECLARE cursor1 SCROLL CURSOR WITH RETURN for ....
```

the deploy would return errors as

> An unexpected token "SCROLL" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "FOR".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.68.61.

The procedure is really simple btw, you can assume it only has this cursor declaration and return.

I googled a lot, still couldn't figure it out why, kind of rookie question, please help show some pointers, million thanks!

Comment: Read the `DECLARE CURSOR` statement description in the manual for your DB2 version and platform.